# Tkinter building windows similar to Root

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently working on Tkinter codes. I happen to need to create new windows exactly similar to root but my codes do not perfectly work well. The title does not appear on the new windows. This is an excerpt:

```
from tkinter import *

#New Window
def New_page():
    window()

#Main Window
def window():

    window = Tk()
    window.resizable(0,0)
    window.configure(background='grey')
    window.state('zoomed')
    window.geometry("2000x4000")

    #Title Frame
    TITLE_FRAME = Frame(window, relief = GROOVE, bg = "black", width=2000, height=160).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan = 150, rowspan = 30, sticky=E+W)
    Label(TITLE_FRAME, text= 'THIS IS THE TITLE PART', fg='sky blue', bg='black', font='none 40 bold', 
          borderwidth=5).grid(row=0,column=10)

    #New Window Button
    ENTRY_FRAME = Frame(window, bg='sky blue', relief = SUNKEN)
    ENTRY_FRAME.grid(row=40, column=0, columnspan=20, padx=15, pady=15)
    Label(ENTRY_FRAME, text= 'SELECT THE APPROPRIATE DETAILS:',
          bg = 'sky blue', fg='black', font='none 10 bold', borderwidth=5).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=20)
    NEW_WINDOW = Button(ENTRY_FRAME, text="NEW WINDOW", font='None 8 bold', width=30, command=New_page, fg= 'black', bg='white')
    NEW_WINDOW.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 3, padx = 10, pady = 10)

    window.mainloop()

#Calling the Tkinter function
window()
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a new window, as in a second window, or replace the current one?

Comment: create multiple similar looking windows

Comment: Calling `Tk()` multiple times leads to various problems.  You have to call it *once*, to get any window at all, but you must then use `Toplevel()` for additional windows.

Comment: that was the one I originally made. But I have the same problem. The title does not appear on the new windows (plus other functions not working but I did not include them the codes above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like in the comments, `Toplevel` is the way to go for this one. What I changed:

1. Moved making the `window` object globally
2. Renamed the function to make it `makeWindow(master)`
3. `makeWindow(master)` now takes in a master widget. This will make
   all of the widgets made there be part of the master window.
4. `New_page` was modified to make a new Toplevel() widget
5. `TITLE_FRAME` is now made first and then grid is called on it

(EDIT) These edits fix the problems with the original window closing the program.

6. We want to remap the closing behaviour to act how we want. This is done with `window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",callback)`. We must define the callback function, in this case, `deleteWindow(win)`.
7. What delete window does is take a window, and if it is the root window it hides it. Otherwise, it deletes the window. I used `window.withdraw()` in my code, but there's probably a better way to do it.
8. The way it knows if it should close the program is by keeping track of the number of active windows in the `activeWindows` variable. When a window is created, the number increases, when delete it decreases. If the number of active windows is 0, we can delete the main window to close the program cleanly.
9. The way we bind the `deleteWindow(win)` callback is through an anonymous function. Normally, the protocol mentioned above does not give any arguments, but we want to know which window called the function. To do this, whenever we bind the destruction of the window, we define a anonymous function using lambda that calls `deleteWindow`.

.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.resizable(0,0)
window.configure(background='grey')
window.state('zoomed')
window.geometry("2000x4000")
activeWindows = 1

def deleteWindow(win):
    if win == window:
        window.withdraw()
    else:
        win.destroy()

    global activeWindows
    activeWindows-=1
    if activeWindows <= 0:
        window.destroy()

#New Window
def New_page():
    global activeWindows
    activeWindows+=1
    NEW_WINDOW=Toplevel(background='grey')
    NEW_WINDOW.geometry("2000x4000")
    NEW_WINDOW.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",lambda:deleteWindow(NEW_WINDOW))
    makeWindow(NEW_WINDOW)

#Main Window
def makeWindow(master):
    #Title Frame
    TITLE_FRAME = Frame(master, relief = GROOVE, bg = "black", width=2000, height=160)
    TITLE_FRAME.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan = 150, rowspan = 30, sticky=E+W)
    Label(TITLE_FRAME, text= 'THIS IS THE TITLE PART', fg='sky blue', bg='black', font='none 40 bold', 
          borderwidth=5).grid(row=0,column=10)

    #New Window Button
    ENTRY_FRAME = Frame(master, bg='sky blue', relief = SUNKEN)
    ENTRY_FRAME.grid(row=40, column=0, columnspan=20, padx=15, pady=15)
    Label(ENTRY_FRAME, text= 'SELECT THE APPROPRIATE DETAILS:',
          bg = 'sky blue', fg='black', font='none 10 bold', borderwidth=5).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=20)
    NEW_WINDOW = Button(ENTRY_FRAME, text="NEW WINDOW", font='None 8 bold', width=30, command=New_page, fg= 'black', bg='white')
    NEW_WINDOW.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 3, padx = 10, pady = 10)

window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",lambda: deleteWindow(window))

#Calling the Tkinter function
makeWindow(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hopefully this is what you want

Comment: thank you very much for this. Just have one problem. If I close the main window, all other windows are also closed. That is actually one of the reasons why I ended up with the codes I shared.

Comment: I'll look into it

Comment: Try and see if the edits work, if not, try playing around with the delete window function and change window.withdraw() to a different function that changes visibility, although how it is now should work.

Comment: thank you very much... this is now working.... Though i still have other concerns (some buttons not working/behaving as expected in the new windows) but they no longer covered with the posted question.... thank you very much